# Drop down list selected value for provided text in java script

Tags: javascript, c#

How can i get drop down list value of selected text in java script?i.e.if my drop down list is containing 10 value from 1 to 10 and text like One to ten for these values('One' for 1,'Two' for 2 ....) .If i am passing text 'Five' then i need to select value 5.

Answer (score 0):

If your dropdown is marked with an id, say 'demo', you could do something like this,

```
var result = document.getElementById("demo");
alert(result.value);
```

You would also have to add a value to each item in your drop down first,

```
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
```

and so on.

Comment: I have Text 'Two'...i need to select value of 'Two'.How can i do?How can i get value of 'Two'?

Comment: You would want to set up your dropdown in such a way,  
<select id="demo">
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
The value would be 2 then.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have following dropdown

```
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Then to get the selected text

```
 $("#dropdown option:selected).Text();
```

To get the selected value.

```
$("#dropdown option: selected).Val()
```